# Source files not working in next.js nor C.R.A., no error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, webpack-5

I am using next.js and as source maps are enabled by default in development, I would expect to have clearer debugging than that:

[image]

I tried disabling all my browser extensions but it changed nothing. I am on Edge 94 and webpack 5. Also tried on Chrome 96.

I also unsuccessfully browsed the 'source' devtools tab, there was no source map here, only compiled code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! - if you press  command+p or control P on the sources (if using chrome or find equivalent in edge ) do you see the source files displayed?

Comment: No, it's only 'webpack://' stuff

Comment: Still not working on NextJS 13. Same cryptic output.